# Adf selectOneChoice valueChangeListener NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

My valueChangeListener for SelectOneChoice is not getting invoked when I am trying to select second Item in the dropdown.
Exemple value="#{bindings.pagents.inputValue" eq 32 in the first select this value but if change other value return null in

> vce.getNewValue().toString()

I'm using JSF 2.2 and Jdeveloper 12.2.1.3.0.

**Code for my SelectOneChoice**

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.pagents.inputValue}"
                                        label="#{bindings.AgentAdvancedFileMedical1.hints.IdtMatag.label}"
                                        autoSubmit="true" immediate="true"
                                        id="soc4" 
                                        binding="#{DossierMedBean.idtagentcodes}"
                                        valueChangeListener="#{DossierMedBean.agentchanged}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.pagents.items}" id="si4"/>
                        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.pagents.validator}"/>
                    </af:selectOneChoice>
```

**Code for my ValueChangeListener**

```
    public void agentchanged(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
       vce.getComponent().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
       Integer value = Integer.parseInt(vce.getNewValue().toString());
       if (vce.getNewValue() != null) {  
        BindingContainer bindings =
                BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
          OperationBinding operationBindinsgs = bindings.getOperationBinding("filterAgentDossierByPartenaire");
       operationBindinsgs.getParamsMap().put("filterAgentStrings",value );
        operationBindinsgs.execute();
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(dossiermed);
        aDFLogger.info("table refreshed successfully!");

        }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post also the code of the validator?

Comment: not validator which contains java bean code add when i add selectOneChoice by default

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your answer, I mean, `<f:validator binding="#{bindings.pagents.validator}"/>`, can you check this validator, or post its code?

Comment: this validator add by default when drag and drop , <af:selectOneChoice>

Comment: problem if at the level of the eterator which does not contain values that is why always return null, my problem solved